# Is it possible to change the default access for new chatter posts?

Tags: community, chatter

We've just recently enabled communities for partner users, and as they're trusted partners we tend to be open-by-default about information with, we'd like to make it so that our chatter is also visible by default to them.

We've configured sharing, CRUD, FLS, etc to meet these goals, but the chatter publisher's **default** is one thing I can't seem to change.

In other words, can we change the default value from "MyCompany Only" to "All With Access"? Or is that something we're stuck doing manually with each post for the moment?

---

[image: chatter publisher visibility settings]

Comment: This applies only to chatter feeds on records and I don't believe that this is configurable but if you created an IdeaExchange idea, I would vote for it.

Comment: @greenstork if there's no answers in a couple days I'll go make one and self-answer with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is not possible today (outside of something unsupported like a browser extension).

I've created an idea petitioning salesforce to build a preference for this: [Allow changing the default community access in the chatter publisher](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DgaLAAS)